# How to learn a Hidden Markov Model with categorical responses in R?

Tags: r, hidden-markov-model

I am looking for a mature library to learn hidden markov models with categorical responses, and I want to be able to learn the HMM from several traces. I tried a few options, but I settled for the [depmixS4 package](https://r-forge.r-project.org/scm/viewvc.php/*checkout*/papers/jss/V1/depmixS4.pdf?root=depmix).

I can learn a model with multinomial responses, but I do not understand the output I get from `summary`. Here is what I did:

```
library(depmixS4)

v = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3)

draws = data.frame(obs = v)

model = depmix(obs ~ 1, data = draws, nstates = 3, family = multinomial())
fm = fit(model)
```

Then, `summary(fm)` gives me:

```
converged at iteration 18 with logLik: -4.612935 
Initial state probabilities model 
pr1 pr2 pr3 
  0   1   0 

Transition matrix 
        toS1  toS2  toS3
fromS1 1.000 0.000 0.000
fromS2 0.000 0.833 0.167
fromS3 0.333 0.000 0.667

Response parameters 
Resp 1 : multinomial 
    Re1.(Intercept).1 Re1.(Intercept).2 Re1.(Intercept).3
St1                 0             4.315            16.664
St2                 0           -13.541           -16.039
St3                 0            14.078             1.221
```

The transition matrix is more or less what I expect, but the Response parameters aren't. I was expected a matrix with shape `n_states x n_observations` containing probabilities, and the first column is all zeroes, so this does not look like what I expected.

Now, the [official documentation of the package](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/depmixS4/versions/1.4-2/topics/responses) states:

> This [the dependent variable] is a binary matrix with N rows and Y columns, where Y is the total number of categories.

But even if I try using one-hot encoding for my variables, I get the same result. Here is the code:

```
v = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3)
v_fact = factor(v) # Factor is a list of categorical data
# One hot encoding, thanks to a magic one liner.
one_hot_v = model.matrix(~ 0 + v_fact)
draws = data.frame(one_hot_v)

model = depmix(v_fact ~ 1, data = draws, nstates = 3, family = multinomial())
fm = fit(model)

summary(fm)
```

Here is the summary.

```
converged at iteration 21 with logLik: -4.61294 
Initial state probabilities model 
pr1 pr2 pr3 
  0   1   0 

Transition matrix 
        toS1  toS2  toS3
fromS1 0.667 0.000 0.333
fromS2 0.167 0.833 0.000
fromS3 0.000 0.000 1.000

Response parameters 
Resp 1 : multinomial 
    Re1.(Intercept).1 Re1.(Intercept).2 Re1.(Intercept).3
St1                 0            12.598            -8.587
St2                 0           -12.960           -14.685
St3                 0             3.099            15.671
```

The summary looks the same as in the previous case.

So I have a few questions:

1. I know my responses (or observations) are discrete and categorical, am I on the right track?
2. How do I read these response parameters? What do they mean? (I would understand `Intercept` if I was doing linear regression, but not in this context).
3. I am interested in the likelihood of observing a value `y` when the chain is in state `s`. How can I see the relationship between a state and the response?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. You are on the right track. A multinomial distribution makes sense here.
2. By default, the submodel for a multinomial response variable will be a multinomial logistic regression model (e.g. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multinomial_logistic_regression) with baseline coding such that the parameters for the first level of the categorical response are fixed to 0. Hence the values of 0 for "Re1.(Intercept).1" (which stands for "response variable 1"."intercept"."level 1") for all states (rows "St"). When you don't include any predictors/regressors/independent variables in this model (i.e. it is an intercept-only model), more directly interpretable parameters can be obtained by using an identity link function, changing your code slightly: family=multinomial("identity"). The parameters are then simply the probability of each level.
3. The state-dependent density of the response variables is given in the "dens" slot of the (fitted) model object, which is "Array of dimension sum(ntimes)*nresp*nstates providing the densities of the observed responses for each state."  (see ?"depmix-class"). So e.g. fm@dens[,,1] will give you the likelihood of the observations assuming the chain is in state 1.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks, helped a lot. Setting using `family = multinomial("identity")`, I get probabilities, which make a lot more sense to me. I didn't find this option since the documentation of the multinomial function is "These are not to be called by the user."...